# What Standard RPC Errors Should I Handle?

Tags: json-rpc, error, exceptions

Is there documentation that lists ALL the types of web3 exceptions that can be thrown by an RPC endpoint? eg. gas price too low, tx already known, etc.? Taking it a step further than that, is there also any standardization on in-contract error language or at least a way to get a list of all the errors a 3rd party contract can possibly throw?

I would like to handle all the cases I possibly can, but don't know where to start.

I found this on the wiki but it doesn't fully map to the actual exception descriptions sent by RPC endpoints like infura.
https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/json-rpc-error-codes-improvement-proposal

This question also seems relevant:
[Elegant way to map web3.js error messages](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45836/elegant-way-to-map-web3-js-error-messages)

Comment: What's the reason to trying to handle all the errors? There's an [EIP 1474 - Remote procedure call specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1474) that documents some of them, but future EIP can incorporate new ones, also client implementors might use others.

Comment: @Ismael I want to handle situations I can, like adding more eth to the account for gas, raising the gas limit, etc. Good code should be robust and resilient to those kinds of issues.